# How to check environment variables in python

Tags: python, oracle11g, cx-oracle

How to check all environment variables in python. I'm trying to install cx_Oracle and instant client and want to make sure all my variables are ok.

Comment: You can use `os.environ` which is a dictionary of the environment variables. You will need to import the `os` module first.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate further on my comment. All environment variables can be found within the `os.environ` dictionary (you'll need to `import os` first).

It looks like `TNS_ADMIN` is one of the environment variables used for `tnsnames.ora`, so you can check like this:

```
import os

if 'TNS_ADMIN' in os.environ:
    print('TNS_ADMIN is set to {}'.format(os.environ['TNS_ADMIN']))
else:
    print('TNS_ADMIN has not been set.')
```